# Why is this link being added to the set?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

This is a node.js program.

I have a link to a webpage and I want to test if it has a specific tag.

If it does, I want to add that link to a set (array with unique values);

I am trying to test if a link has a input of type 'submit'. If it returns undefined, I will add it to a set.

Here is my code so far:

```
//Modules being used:
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

//harcoded url
var url = 'http://shirts4mike.com/';

// Load front page of shirts4mike
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var urlSet = new Set();

        //iterate over links with 'shirt'
        $("a[href*=shirt]").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr('href');

            //create new link
            var scrapeLink = url + a;

            //for each new link, go in and find out if there is a submit button. If there, add it to the set
            request(scrapeLink, function(error,response, html){
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                    if($('[type=submit]') !== undefined){

                        urlSet.add(scrapeLink);

                        console.log(urlSet);
                    } 
                }
            }); 
        });
    }
});
```

Right now, the last set printed out will be like this:

```
Set {
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=106',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=108',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=107' }
```

Most of them are right, however, I cannot find anywhere a submit button on `'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php'`, so why is it being added to the set?

Is it because the other links are linked to from it and it's just diving all the way inside?

Comment: sorted that part :)

Comment: Ok, now you have a timing issue.  Your codes says: start some network requests, print out their results, and then wait for them to respond.  I recommend you check out http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: Ah, I've fixed that part, well not fixed, but I understand what's going on there. If I move the console log to the right part, I get this: 

`Set {
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=108',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=107',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=106' }`

Which is more or less right. However I cannot find any submit anywhere on 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php`. That page does link to the others though, so is possible that it's diving all the way through to the end?

Comment: The element isn't `<submit>`, it's `<input type='submit'>` you'll need to query by type.

Comment: I see, why is it being added to the set then? :S

Comment: I get the exact same output if I do this: `if($('[type=submit]') !== undefined)`